# Help to create this image with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, mdframed

[image]

i don't know how create this theorem with tikz and amsthm packages

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: And what should happen if the last line ends at the right margin?

Comment: Where are you going to use this? I would probably try using a `tcolorbox` (with a Ti*k*Z overlay for the decorations).

Comment: @Thérèse yes but we can find a a solution

Comment: @JasperHabicht i don't know how?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank , tizk and tcolorbox

Comment: If you tried something already, it would be nice if you could share your code. It might be better to help you improving it than doing something completely new (which might not suit your needs exactly).

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter]{mytheorem}{Theorem}{%
    enhanced,
    empty,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    lefttitle=1cm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=15mm},
    overlay={\draw (title.west)-|([yshift=15mm]frame.south west);
    \draw ([yshift=-15mm]frame.north east)--([yshift=5mm]frame.south east)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.south east)--++(180:2cm);
    \draw ([yshift=3mm]frame.south east)--([xshift=-3mm]frame.south east);}
}{th}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytheorem}{}{a}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mytheorem}
 
 \begin{mytheorem}{Second theorem}{b}
 As you can see in Theorem~\ref{th:a} \dots
 
\lipsum[1]
\end{mytheorem}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the line going from the section title to the left in the original picture is blue in the picture the OP provided (but I don't know whether this is intended =) ) ...